# Creating DNF with variable in output column

Tags: vhdl, boolean-algebra

I am trying to model an Arbiter in VHDL. For this I've created a Moore automaton and am currently mapping the output.

The output should be when mapping from the state:

```
z1 z0 | y
0   0 | 0000
0   1 | inB
1   0 | inA
1   1 | inA
```

So basically depending on the state z either inB, inA or 0000 should be passed to the output y.

How can I model this in a DNF? I would usually process by finding the y rows with a 1 in it, but here I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
y <= inA WHEN z1 = '1' ELSE inB WHEN z0 = '1' ELSE "0000"
```

Or did I missunderstand your question?

Comment: No, thanks this is correct. I thought that I had to do this without any VHDL features like `when` and use only logic gates, but this is also fine. Helped me solve the problem.